# Escribir comando en terminal con script

Tags: linux, script, cmd, terminal, sh

¿Hay alguna forma de poder ejecutar un script que abra una terminal y escriba un comando en ella?

Necesito hacerlo, pero abro la terminal y a la hora de escribir el comando no sé como resolverlo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nota**: esta respuesta está basada en [esta otra](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the/46630#46630) de https://askubuntu.com/

En general la forma es

```
terminal -e <comando o path a otro script>
```

Es decir, si usas Gnome sería algo como

```
gnome-terminal -e
```

y en KDE sería

```
konsole -e comando
```